# Spring Boot configure https, TLS only via properties file

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to configure `Spring Boot 2.5` using **only** **.properties* *(*.yml)* files
to provide https (TLS) and disable http? I'm asking this, because I don't want to change
anything in my code and I want for different environments to have an easily configurable way to enable or disable security features.

P.S.

I'm using an embedded Tomcat container

my controller looks like this

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping(value = "/test",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyObject> generateResponse(
            @RequestBody RequestDto requestDto) throws IOException {
         <...>
    }
}
```

Every configuration set that I've seen involves some kind of addition to the code like
(taken from https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/)

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
      .requiresChannel(channel -> 
          channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure())
      .authorizeRequests(authorize ->
          authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())
      .build();
    }

}
```

or this (taken from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate)

```
RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
      .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getURL(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
      .build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
      .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
      .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = 
      new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/**")
      .permitAll();
}
```

If it is impossible to avoid code tinkering how to achieve configurability of http / https via some property switch involving a code change? Also, I would like to avoid going back and forth between different profiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing docs I realized that it is quite simple

all you need to do is

```
--server.ssl.enabled=true 
--server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12 
--server.ssl.key-store="path/to/your/public/key/store/public_key.p12" 
--server.ssl.key-store-password=password
```

and for extra you can also add

```
--server.http2.enabled=true
```

to enable http2 protocol.